# Gulp stuck on Starting 'some_task_name' if used gulp.parallel or gulp.series

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, gulp-watch

Suddenly working gulp config stop working. It hangs on `'Starting...'`  if i use task with `gulp.parallel` or `gulp.series`. Yesterday same config worked flawlessly, why this happen?

Simplified example:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');

const paths = {
    styles: './scss/**/*'
}

gulp.task('debug', () => {
    console.log('debug')
})

gulp.task('parallel', () => {
    gulp.watch(paths.styles, gulp.parallel('debug'))
})

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('debug'));
```

Node version: **v12.18.2**
Gulp: **4.0.2**
Gulp-cli: **2.3.0**

Comment: What version of gulp are you using?

Comment: @AlexanderBenjamin 4.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Here is corrected working versin:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');

const paths = {
    styles: './scss/**/*'
}

gulp.task('debug', (done) => {
    console.log('debug')
    done();
})

gulp.task('parallel', (done) => {
  gulp.watch( paths.styles, gulp.parallel( 'debug' ) )
  done();
})

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('debug'));
```

You need to sygnal the completion of the task by calling a callback. In this case it is `done()` callback.

See [Async Completion](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/async-completion)

Hope this helps.

Comment: unfortunately result is still the same "Starting..."

Comment: did you try deleting node_modules, package.lock and running npm install?

Comment: I edited the answer - you also need the `done` callback in the `parallel` task.